# Where is .Net Core Project Templates?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, project-template

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019), all templates are in the following path

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\<edition>\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\<Language>\<Locale ID>
```

But I could not find the .NET Core templates and only the .NET Framework templates are available.

Where are the .NET Core templates (which Visual Studio itself uses to build the WPF/Console/Winform Application)?

Answer (score 0):

They are located at [user profile path].templateengine\dotnetcli\vX.X.XXX\packages\